# SonarLint: Return an empty collection instead of null

Tags: java, spring-boot, sonarlint

I'm making an ajax call to a method that returns a list of object, if something happens while getting the data in a try-catch block I have a `response.setStatus(400)` to then show the error in the front-end, also there I'm returning null, there is where I'm getting the SonarLint notification. Now if I change that to an empty collection then I get below error:

`getWriter() has already been called for this response`

I think the above is because I'm returning the empty collection and the http response status 400. If I leave it null then all works fine, just that SonarLint notification.

```
@GetMapping("/runquery")
@ResponseBody
public List<Map<String, Object>> runQuery(@RequestParam(name = "queryId") String queryId, @RequestParam(name = "formData") String formData, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    (...)

    try {
        queryResult = namedParameterJdbcTemplateHive.queryForList(query, paramSource);

        for (Map<String, Object> map : queryResult) {
            Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {                    
                String key = entry.getKey();
                Object value = entry.getValue();

                if (key.contains(".")) {
                    key = key.replace(".", "_");
                    newMap.put(key, value);
                } else {
                    newMap.put(key, value);
                }
            }
            queryResultFinal.add(newMap);
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
        response.setStatus(400);
        response.getWriter().write(e.getMessage());
        return null;  <-- SonarLint notification
    }

    return queryResultFinal;        
}
```

Any idea on how to fix this notification?

Comment: `if something happens while getting the data in a try-catch block I have a response.setStatus(400)` - 4xx errors are for client related problems, you should return 5xx. Maybe better to let exception propagate and have exceptionmapper wired via @ControllerAdvice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not catching the exception in this method, but instead throw it, and use an [exception handler method](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler) in your controller to handle it. In that case you will never return `null` from the method, and Sonar will have nothing to complain about. It will also mean that you are using Spring the way it is designed to be used.

For example, something like the following:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public void handleException(Exception e) {
    log.error("Exception during request", e);
}
```

or the direct equivalent of your current handling:

```
@ExceptionHandler
public ResponseEntity<?> handleException(Exception e) {
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage()).build();
}
```

You can remove the `HttpServletResponse response` parameter from your normal method after switching to an exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to create a **GenericReponse** that wraps all of your responses, it's pretty good for front-end also because you're facing with a fixed template.

So via this solution, you can wrap up any object you want and send it to the response.

---

I coded the scenario like this:

**1- Create a GenericResponse Class**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GenericResponse {

    private Boolean error;
    private List<ErrorPayload> errorPayload;
    private Object payload;

    public GenericResponse(Boolean error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public static GenericResponse ok() {
        return new GenericResponse(false);
    }

     public GenericResponse payload(Serializable o) {
         this.payload = o;
         return this;
     }

    //Getters and Setters and other Constructors
```

**2-Create ErrorPayload Class**

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ErrorPayload {

    private String errorMessage;
    private String errorType;

//Getters and Setters and Constructors
}
```

**3-Create ExceptionConverter Service (Used when we have exception)**

```
@Service
public class ExceptionConverterService {

    public GenericResponse convert(Exception x) {

        GenericResponse genericResponse = new GenericResponse();
        genericResponse.setError(true);
        String exceptionType = x.getClass().getSimpleName();
        String exceptionMessage = x.getClass().getSimpleName();
        genericResponse.setErrorPayload(Collections.singletonList(new ErrorPayload(exceptionType, exceptionMessage)));
        return genericResponse;

    }

}
```

**4-Change Your scenario with GenericResponse**

All you need to do is:

1. Create aforementioned classes (Copy the code that I wrote in 1, 2 and 3)
2. Change your response form `List<Map<String, Object>>` to `GenericResponse`
3. Wrap your return types into `GenericResponse`

I changed your code as follows (Just change 3 lines)

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionConverterService exceptionConverter;

    @GetMapping("/runquery")
    @ResponseBody
    //Changed (Change Return type to GenericResponse )
    public GenericResponse runQuery(@RequestParam(name = "queryId") String queryId, @RequestParam(name = "formData") String formData, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {


        try {
            //Your code
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            //Changed (Create GenericResponse for Exception)
            GenericResponse genericResponse = exceptionConverter.convert(e);
            return genericResponse;
        }

        //Changed (Create GenericResponse for main result)
        return GenericResponse.ok().payload(queryResultFinal);
    }

}
```

---

Examples for two scenarios (first, without exception and the second with exception)

**Sample 1**

Controller with GenericResponse (We have no exception in this sample)

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping(value = "/getNameAndFamily")
    public GenericResponse getNameAndFamily() {

        Map<String, String> person = new HashMap<>();
        person.put("name", "foo");
        person.put("family", "bar");
        return GenericResponse.ok().payload((Serializable) person);
    }

}
```

The result is like as follows:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "payload": {
        "name": "foo",
        "family": "bar"
    }
}
```

**Sample 2**

controller with GenericResponse when we have Exception in business

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private ExceptionConverterService exceptionConverter;

    @GetMapping(value = "/getNameAndFamily")
    public GenericResponse getNameAndFamily() {

        try {

            //Create Fake Exception
            int i = 1 / 0;
            return GenericResponse.ok();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            //Handle Exception
            GenericResponse genericResponse = exceptionConverter.convert(e);
            return GenericResponse.ok().payload((Serializable) genericResponse);

        }
    }

}
```

The result is as follows:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "errorPayload": [
        {
            "errorType": "ArithmeticException"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is not what `Serializable` is intended for. `Serializable` is for the Java binary serialization, it is not intended for nor needed for serialization to json. Using `Object` as the parameter type of the `payload` method would be good enough.